# What's a free/lightweight way to email a message to force an iPhone alert?

Tags: iphone, applications, email, sms, apns

At my job, we get specific emails that need to be responded to right away.

Currently, I filter and forward those emails to my SMS gateway address provided by AT&T (1234567890@txt.att.net). The problem is that they result in 16 text messages because there are 4 emails and each one results in 4 text messages.

Can anyone recommend a service or app that provides an email address that will result in an iPhone popup?

Comment: How about just displaying a "popup" notification of the email received as a regular email on the iPhone?

Comment: I only want a popup on a particular "From" address, which is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you'll find a free one, because it costs money to maintain a server, the server in which you need to use with some software set up to communicate with the Apple Push Notification Service ("APNS").

We use [Prowl](http://prowlapp.com/) (link goes to homepage, [here is](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prowl-growl-client/id320876271?mt=8) an iTunes App Store Link) at work in order to send Monitoring (NAGIOS) notifications to our phones. It's a $3 app, but it's also infinitely flexible.

It gives you an e-mail address you can use to just shoot notifications too, but it also offers an API you can use to do a lot of special things with.

More details if requested after you check out Zac's site. (Zac is the developer/maintainer/operator of Prowl app and it's associated server backend.)

Comment: Thanks VxJasonxV. Prowl allows you create an email address from the API key. This was very easy to set up. I now forward my email from Google Voice to the API key email address (40285a2b74f2c02fe250593e97ea8722c58056d3@api.prowlapp.com). The problem is that Google Voice does not give you an email address that you can send a text message to. Other providers provide an email address such 12345678990@vtext.com (Verizon Wireless) so you can text somebody via email.

Comment: That is true, and is a recent feature. Glad it works fo ryou. P.S. You may want to delete your comment, because you're not supposed to generally give out your API key.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Popups, but your iPhone can get emails **pushed** through gmail. Would that help?

Also, whatever forwards to SMS could trim the email so that each only takes 1 SMS to deliver.

Answer (score 0):

My original intent was to enable push support for my mail server and the following recommendation works pretty well for dozens of mails per hour with usually brilliant, rarely not-so-jolly response times.

There are a couple of choices in the App Store. The first I found bearable is [Boxcar](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/boxcar/id321493542?mt=8). It is an app coupled with a service that provides you access to Apple Push Notification Service in a form of a unique e-mail address which you can forward mail to.

It has a variety of notifications, but the best idea is to set it to merely display badges with mail information and play a sound.

The downside is that you have to pipe your mail through a third party but you have a choice to filter forwarded mail on your own mail server, which you already do.

I find it blazing fast most of the time (95%) with response times measured in sub-4 seconds, but there are cases (5%) where the delivery lag jitters highly. I have seen messages appear on the desktop computer 15 minutes before the push arrived.

Still, it's easy to configure and it is actually convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can send whatever notification using phone pipe:

https://github.com/drewcrawford/Phone-Pipe

You will need the free Notifo app for this, check the itunes store.

Answer (score 0):

Google Voice is pretty good for this kind of stuff, and it's free.